# Diagnosing why WebResource.axd requests are empty on IE browser

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a ASP.NET application that uses AJAX toolkit. When I navigate to a screen in IE, I get the following errors :

```
Message: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Type Sys.WebForms.BeginRequestEventArgs has already been registered. The type may be defined multiple times or the script file that defines it may have already been loaded. A possible cause is a change of settings during a partial update.
URI: https://<ApplicationDomain>/<VirtualDirectory>/<SessionId>/OverrideExternalAJAXScriptFiles/System.Web.Extensions/1.0.61025.0/MicrosoftAjax.js

Message: Sys.InvalidOperationException: The PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once.
URI: https://<ApplicationDomain>/<VirtualDirectory>/ScriptResource.axd?d=1kB1uVOc_24H5Yv0czI8zYXbvBXwR3XEjx30oYmCmGTKnIO-YRd60i8TTRVkjRbqAOUbgzJ5E3y6NrTt4IHX7drIQC3kzAvPOpZn7KXUJOc1&t=633694372944218750

Message: Sys.ArgumentException:  does not derive from Sys.Component.
URI: https://<ApplicationDomain>/<VirtualDirectory>/<SessionId>/OverrideExternalAJAXScriptFiles/System.Web.Extensions/1.0.61025.0/MicrosoftAjax.js
```

Also a blank screen opens in a new tab. This blank screen has the url

```
https://<ApplicationDomain>/<VirtualDirectory>/WebResource.axd?d=oHc_bhKp0frEM0H6NvUwjw2&t=634625324512398510.
```

This problem occurs only on IE. Firefox and Google Chrome browsers work fine. The web application uses the older version of the ASP.Net Ajax toolkit(version 1.0.61025.0). The web application also overrides MicrosoftAjax.js, MicrosoftAjaxTimer.js, MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js. The web application uses "ScriptManager"

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
             <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" ScriptMode="Auto" Path="~/OverrideExternalAJAXScriptFiles/System.Web.Extensions/1.0.61025.0/MicrosoftAjax.js" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Would we have  pointers on how should I go about debugging and fixing this problem? I am at my wits end.

Comment: Are you using a ToolkitScriptManager or something else?

Comment: My web application uses ScriptManager and a older version of the AJAX toolkit.

Comment: I would try using ToolkitScriptManager instead of ScriptManager to see if that may help.  Also, if Telerik has a ScriptManager, try using it as well.